Why won't Jupyter Notebook (or Lab) open in Anaconda Navigator or cmd
I've tried opening Jupyter notebook through anaconda navigator, as well as in the anaconda cmd.exe command line. Anaconda Navigator will show that blue loading bar in the bottom right corner but nothing happens. Trying to open with the command line gives me this output.
jupyter notebook
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:24.387 ServerApp] Extension package aext_assistant took 0.1660s to import
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:24.402 ServerApp] ****************** ENVIRONMENT Environment.PRODUCTION ******************
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:24.402 ServerApp] ****************** ENVIRONMENT Environment.PRODUCTION ******************
[W 2024-08-13 12:26:24.433 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in jupyter_lsp. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[W 2024-08-13 12:26:24.495 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in notebook_shim. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.303 ServerApp] Extension package panel.io.jupyter_server_extension took 0.8029s to import
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.303 ServerApp] aext_assistant | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.303 ServerApp] aext_core | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.303 ServerApp] aext_panels | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.303 ServerApp] aext_share_notebook | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.303 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.303 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.303 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.313 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.548 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.548 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.580 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.580 ServerApp] Registered aext_assistant server extension
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.580 ServerApp] aext_assistant | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.580 ServerApp] Registered aext_core server extension
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.580 ServerApp] aext_core | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.580 ServerApp] Registered aext_panels server extension
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.580 ServerApp] aext_panels | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.580 ServerApp] Registered aext_share_notebook_server server extension
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.580 ServerApp] aext_share_notebook | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.580 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.580 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.595 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Software\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.595 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Software\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.595 LabApp] Extension Manager is 'pypi'.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.595 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.604 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.604 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.604 ServerApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.604 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\NETL-ris398
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.604 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 2.14.1 is running at:
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.604 ServerApp] http://localhost:8889/tree?token=4c9608e761cdbbe288c4bd627c6e4ef5c03ef28e3b7adff1
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.604 ServerApp]     http://127.0.0.1:8889/tree?token=4c9608e761cdbbe288c4bd627c6e4ef5c03ef28e3b7adff1
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.611 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2024-08-13 12:26:25.627 ServerApp]

    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/NETL-ris398/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-28988-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8889/tree?token=4c9608e761cdbbe288c4bd627c6e4ef5c03ef28e3b7adff1
        http://127.0.0.1:8889/tree?token=4c9608e761cdbbe288c4bd627c6e4ef5c03ef28e3b7adff1
[I 2024-08-13 12:26:25.704 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed server(s): bash-language-server, dockerfile-language-server-nodejs, javascript-typescript-langserver, jedi-language-server, julia-language-server, pyright, python-language-server, r-languageserver, sql-language-server, texlab, typescript-language-server, unified-language-server, vscode-css-languageserver-bin, vscode-html-languageserver-bin, vscode-json-languageserver-bin, yaml-language-server

This is still running, blinking cursor and all, without erroring or progressing. I'm not sure what part of this output indicates a problem. May be interesting to note, despite what it says, inputting Control-c does not stop it.
I have updated conda, my environment, and jupyter as well as running install for all of these to ensure that they were on my computer at all. At one point I was getting a package inconsistency error but that was fixed with conda update --all

Did you open a browser and put in the address http://127.0.0.1:8889/tree?token=4c9608e761cdbbe288c4bd627c6e4ef5c03ef28e3b7adff1? (That comes from the bottom of your code block, just above "This is still running, blinking cursor and all, without erroring or progressing.") That output you show in the code block is a nicely running server providing Jupyter to you on your local computer. So it appears it works, hence your title is wrong. I suspect you may also have Anaconda running too because it says The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port. 8888 is usually the default port. ...

 Or maybe it didn't get shutdown right? Anyway, you need that running in that window so you can use it over in your browser. Specically, "still running, blinking cursor and all, without erroring or progressing" is good. That is what you want.  .... As for it not working from Anaconda, it is concerning to see C:\Software\anaconda3\ earlier in that and then  C:/Users/NETL-ris398/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/ without Anaconda in the path. Did you have an installation of Jupyter that didn't use Anaconda before and it is interferring?
